# Untrain expressions in wit

Tags: wit.ai

I input expression `dont` and wit doesn't recognize it as expected.

If I create a trait entity `yes_no` and label `dont` as `yes_no` with value `no` then the next time I input expression `dont`, wit outputs `yes_no` with value `no`.

My question is how could I untrain `dont` without removing `yes_no` entity or `no` value?
I mean how could I make it so wit doesn't recognize it as `no` like before? 
I've tried to remove `dont` from list of expressions in `yes_no` entity but wit still recognize `dont` as `no`.

Edit:
I test it again and wit run as expected, wit doesn't recognize `dont` after some time or after I label some data in inbox and training status is green. I think wit needs some time to retrain the model, I don't know how long though.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I work on Wit)

It looks like Wit applies the keyword strategy here. You can remove `dont` from your list of keywords by going in the Understanding tab and clicking on the name of your entity.

Comment: It was trait entity. I test it again and wit run as expected, wit doesn't recognize `dont` after some time or after I label some data in inbox and training status is green. I think wit needs some time to retrain the model, I don't know how long though.